Get origin $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] cors whitelist domain name get origin is null?
$origin = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : null;

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $allowed_domain");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
header("X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM $origin");
header("Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' $allowed_domain");

this code origin cors whitelist domain, but get $origin all null?

So apparently $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] was not set to begin with then. It looks like you are not actually trying to use that value for a CORS setting, but for X-Frame-Options. The browser requesting a URL because it was embedded as an iframe, does not mean you will get an Origin request header.

$origin = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : null;
I have an example Cors whitelist domain name, server one has video content and I have serve two for embedding iframe server one, what is the problem I get cross-origin always null $origin.

Please clarify, what exactly you are actually embedding, and how. Is it an HTML document that contains a video element, are you pointing the iframe src to a video URL directly, or something completely different altogether?

If you are talking about a video element - you need to set the crossorigin attribute appropriately, if you want the browser to send an Origin header.
